# How to display a stitch of TIFF images, allowing zooming and moving

Tags: java, tiff, jai

I want to write a simple Java application to display a portion of large stitched tiles of TIFF images. I want to be able to zoom and move around.

Is using [JAI](https://jai.dev.java.net/) the best current way to go? The documentation seems awfully out-of-date.

I found this [sample program to display a TIFF image](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/Examples.doc.html). But how can I zoom into a TIFF image? And is it possible to stitch multiple images and seemingly move into a portion, regardless of the image boundaries?

Comment: You will probably need a large amount of memory, so a 64-bit OS may be necessary, if you are loading lots of imaages at once, so they can zoom out and see everything, but, JAI seems like the best option, though I haven't used it for years.

Comment: You will want to use an AffineTransform for zooming, I believe you can get a java awt Image from JAI so this page may be useful. http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Image-Viewer/Image_viewer.html

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. Is there a way not to need too much memory, if we limit the zoom out, and only have at most four images on the screen at once?